# How to make relative path when adding linker libraries in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, relative-path

When we include `C++` directories, there is an option to make a **relative path**. However, there is no similar option when we add `linker` libraries. I can change things to make a relative path by modifying the Netbeans configuration file manually but I do not think it's a good practice.